# Required field validator preventing panel to display

Tags: c#, asp.net, modalpopupextender, requiredfieldvalidator

I am using 2 link buttons (Coordinator and Staff) which on_Click action displays corresponding panels asking for login/signup/forgotpassword. If the user select signup/forgotpassword a popup windows is popped (using ModalPopupExtender) asking for information. Everything worked fine unless and until I used required field validator within the panel which pops up when the user click on signup/forgotpassword. If I use required field validator my page run fine and when I click on any of the link button (Coordinator/Staff) nothing happens.
 This is aspx code :

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type = "text/css">
        .modalBackground 
    { 
        background-color: gray; 
    }
    .modalPopup 
    { 
        background-color: white; 
        border-width: 3px; 
        border-style: solid; 
        border-color: black; 
        padding-top: 10px; 
        padding-left: 10px; 
        width: 300px; 
        height: 140px;
    }
    .panel
    {
        background : gray;
        padding : 10px;
    }
    div ul ul 
    {
        display: none;
    }
    div ul li:hover > ul 
    {
        display: block;
    }
    div ul li ul:hover > ul 
    {
        display: block;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="XX-Large" Text="Automated Examination System"></asp:Label><br />&nbsp;<br /><br />&nbsp;
    <asp:Panel ID = "MainPanel" runat = "server" Height="181px" Width="275px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <ul>
    <li style="margin-left: 33px; width: 169px;">&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID = "LinkAdmin" runat = "server" onclick="LinkAdmin_Click">Coordinator</asp:LinkButton></li>
    <li style="width: 172px; margin-left: 33px">&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkStaff" runat="server" onclick="LinkStaff_Click">Staff</asp:LinkButton></li>
    <li style="margin-left: 33px">&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID = "LinkStudent" runat = "server">Student</asp:LinkButton>
            <ul>
            <li><asp:LinkButton ID = "LinkButton1" runat = "server">Fresh Registration</asp:LinkButton></li>
            <li><asp:LinkButton ID = "LinkButton2" runat = "server">Re Registration</asp:LinkButton></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel ID="InfoPanel" runat="server" style="left: 290px; top: 104px; position: absolute; height: 375px; width: 611px"><br /><br /><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Medium" Text="The Automated Examination system will allow post graduation student and under graduation students to register their respective courses for their respective semester. "></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Medium" Text="Once the registration process is completed for a student the system sends information to the controller of examination."></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Medium" Text="Each staff will be able to enter the CIE1 and CIE2 marks based on the privileges provided by coordinator of that respective department. "></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Medium" Text="Once the staff enters marks for CIE1/CIE2, they won’t be allowed to make changes later on. "></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Medium" Text="After submitting the marks, the staff will be given with print out of the entered marks for further reference. "></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Medium" Text="At the end of a semester each student SGPA is calculated and the controller take a back up copy of grade cards and result sheet of all the students. "></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Medium" Text="Since student grades are sensitive information certain measures are taken to prevent unauthorized access. "></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Medium" Text="The system also generate the transcript of student which contains all semester marks, Course Title in that particular semester, SGPA of each semester and overall CGPA of that student. "></asp:Label>
    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel ID="AdminLogin" runat="server" style= "left: 906px; top: 105px; position: absolute; " Visible="False" Width="430px"><br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text="Coordinator Login"></asp:Label><br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text="Select Department : "></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"  ValidationGroup="AdminLogin"></asp:DropDownList>&nbsp;
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="AdminReq1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownList1" ErrorMessage="Department is blank" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="AdminLogin"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text="Select Branch : "></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" ValidationGroup="AdminLogin"></asp:DropDownList>&nbsp;
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="AdminReq2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownList2" ErrorMessage="Branch is blank" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="AdminLogin"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text="Username : "></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="AdminTxt1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="AdminLogin" style="height: 22px"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="AdminReq3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="AdminTxt1" ErrorMessage="Username is blank" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="AdminLogin"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text="Password : "></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="AdminTxt2" runat="server" TextMode="Password" ValidationGroup="AdminLogin"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="AdminReq4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="AdminTxt2" ErrorMessage="Password is blank" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="AdminLogin"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="AdminLog" runat="server" Text="Login" Width="80px" ValidationGroup="AdminLogin" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="AdminSignUp" runat="server" Text="New Coordinator" Width="110px"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="AdminForPwd" runat="server" Text="Forgot Password" />
     </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel ID="StaffLogin" runat="server" style="left: 906px; top: 105px; position: absolute;" Visible="False" Width="430px"><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" Text="Staff Login"></asp:Label><br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label16" runat="server" Text="Username : "></asp:Label>&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="StaffTxt1" runat="server" Width="127px" ValidationGroup="StaffLogin"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="StaffReq1" runat="server" ControlToValidate=" StaffTxt1" ErrorMessage="Username is blank" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="StaffLogin"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label17" runat="server" Text="Password : "></asp:Label>&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="StaffTxt2" runat="server" TextMode="Password" ValidationGroup="StaffLogin"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="StaffReq2" runat="server" ControlToValidate=" StaffTxt2" ErrorMessage="Password is blank" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="StaffLogin"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="StaffLog" runat="server" Text="Login" Width="80px" ValidationGroup="StaffLogin" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="StaffSignUp" runat="server" Text="New Staff" Width="82px"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="StaffForPwd" runat="server" Text="Forgot Password" Width="110px" />
    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel ID="StaffSP" CssClass="modalPopup" style="display: none" runat="server">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label18" runat="server" Text="Staff Sign Up" Font-Size="XX-Large"></asp:Label><br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label19" runat="server" Text="Enter Course Code : "></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="StaffSPTxt1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="StaffSPReq1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Course Code is BLANK" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="StaffSPTxt1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label20" runat="server" Text="Enter Password : "></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="StaffSPTxt2" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="StaffSPReq2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Password is BLANK" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="StaffSPTxt2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label21" runat="server" Text="Retype Password : "></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="StaffSPTxt3" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:CompareValidator ID="StaffSPCom1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Password Mismatch" ForeColor="Red" ControlToCompare="StaffSPTxt2" ControlToValidate="StaffSPTxt3"></asp:CompareValidator><br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label22" runat="server" Text="Enter Password Hint : "></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="StaffSPTxt4" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="StaffSPReq3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Password Hint is BLANK" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="StaffSPTxt4"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Sign Up" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel ID="StaffFP" CssClass="modalPopup" style="display: none" runat="server">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label23" runat="server" Text="Staff Forgot Password" Font-Size="XX-Large"></asp:Label><br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label24" runat="server" Text="Enter Username : "></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="StaffFPTxt1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="StaffFPReq1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Username is BLANK" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="StaffFPTxt1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label25" runat="server" Text="Enter Password Hint : "></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="StaffFPTxt2" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="StaffFPReq2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Hint is BLANK" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="StaffFPTxt2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" Text="GetPassword" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button6" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel ID="AdminSP" CssClass="modalPopup" style="display: none" runat="server">&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label26" runat="server" Text="Coordinator Sign Up" Font-Size="XX-Large"></asp:Label><br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label27" runat="server" Text="Select Department : "></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:DropDownList ID="AdminSPDrp1" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="AdminSPReq1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Department is BLANK" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="AdminSPDrp1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label28" runat="server" Text="Select Branch : "></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:DropDownList ID="AdminSPDrp2" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="AdminSPReq2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Branch is BLANK" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="AdminSPDrp2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label29" runat="server" Text="Enter Username : "></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="AdminSPTxt1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="AdminSPReq3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Username is BLANK" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="AdminSPTxt1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label30" runat="server" Text="Enter Password : "></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="AdminSPTxt2" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="AdminSPReq4" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Password is BLANK" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="AdminSPTxt2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label31" runat="server" Text="Retype Password : "></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="AdminSPTxt3" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:CompareValidator ID="AdminSPCom1" runat="server" ControlToValidate = "AdminSPTxt3" ControlToCompare = "AdminSPTxt2" ErrorMessage="Password Mismatch" ForeColor="Red"></asp:CompareValidator><br /><br />&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label32" runat="server" Text="Enter Password Hint : "></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="AdminSPTxt4" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="AdminSPReq5" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Hint is BLANK" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="AdminSPTxt4"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button7" runat="server" Text="Sign Up" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button8" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel ID="AdminFP" CssClass="modalPopup" style="display: none" runat="server">&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label33" runat="server" Text="Coordinator Forgot Password" Font-Size="XX-Large"></asp:Label><br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label34" runat="server" Text="Select Department : "></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:DropDownList ID="AdminFPDrp1" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="AdminFPReq1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Department is BLANK" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="AdminFPDrp1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label35" runat="server" Text="Select Branch : "></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:DropDownList ID="AdminFPDrp2" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="AdminFPReq2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Branch is BLANK" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="AdminFPDrp2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label36" runat="server" Text="Enter Username : "></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="AdminFPTxt1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="AdminFPReq3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Username is BLANK" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="AdminFPTxt1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label37" runat="server" Text="Enter Password Hint : "></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="AdminFPTxt2" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="AdminFPReq4" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Hint is BLANK" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="AdminFPTxt2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button9" runat="server" Text="Sign Up" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button10" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
    </asp:Panel>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" PopupControlID = "StaffSP" CancelControlID = "Button4" TargetControlID = "StaffSignUp" runat="server"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
        <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender2" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" PopupControlID = "StaffFP" CancelControlID = "Button6" TargetControlID = "StaffForPwd" runat="server"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
        <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender3" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" PopupControlID = "AdminSP" CancelControlID = "Button8" TargetControlID = "AdminSignUp" runat="server"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
        <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender4" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" PopupControlID = "AdminFP" CancelControlID = "Button10" TargetControlID = "AdminForPwd" runat="server"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is code behind page :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class MasterFinal : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void LinkAdmin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AdminLogin.Visible = true;
        StaffLogin.Visible = false;
    }
    protected void LinkStaff_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AdminLogin.Visible = false;
        StaffLogin.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure that buttons you don't need validation for have CausesValidation="false" set on them. Also make sure that your buttons that you want to use validation on are in the same validationgroup as your validators.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark. I am so stupid to miss out on that. Thank you once again.